# Is it safe to not implement HttpPostActionInterface?

Tags: magento2

Is it safe to not implement HttpPostActionInterface ?

From:

```
class NewAction extends SubscriberController implements HttpPostActionInterface
```

To:

```
class NewAction extends SubscriberController
```

My goal on removing the **implement HttpPostActionInterface** was to prevent the page on displaying the 404 page if no post was sent. Our requirement was only to display a blank page when user manually load the link.

Or if you have other option on displaying blank page instead displaying 404 not found content.

Other Classes connected/extended that might help:

**SubscriberController**

```
abstract class Subscriber extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
```

**\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action**

```
abstract class Action extends AbstractAction
```

**AbstractAction**

```
abstract class AbstractAction implements \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Controller Must Implement POST or GET Action Interface Class Other wise it will give you `404 No Found` to your request

if your controller `SubscriberController` is implement any of ActionInterface its okay you don't need to implement that again

**Update**

The Class `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` can be used but it is depreciated after Magneto 2.4 so it's a good practice to implement `PostActionInterface`

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply,

the **SubscriberController** doesn't implement it, but it extends **\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action** . Is it okay ?

Comment: I updated also my question, can you check if it still need to implement the HttpPostActionInterface or is it okay not ?

Comment: check my updated answer